# Adding pictureBox to panel with codes

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, picturebox

I have a panel in Visual Studio/windows form app.But I coulnd't add pictureBox on it with code.It is working if I work without panel however I need it.MyCodes:

```
      PictureBox[] pipe = new PictureBox[3];

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreatePipes(1);}

    private void CreatetopPipes(int Number)
    {
          for (int i = 0; i <= Number; i++)
        {

            PictureBox temp = new PictureBox();
            this.Controls.Add(temp);
            temp.Width = 50;
            temp.Height = 350;
            temp.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            temp.BackColor = Color.Red;
            temp.Top = 30;
            temp.Left = 300;
            topPipe[i] = temp;
            topPipe[i].Visible = true;


        }
    }
```

Comment: `this` - is a `Form`. Use your panel instead.

Comment: And don't stack them all at the same location!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `panelName.Controls.Add(temp)`, and i advise you to change a top of `PictureBox` in `for loop` to view all `PictureBox`, like this :

```
private void CreatetopPipes(int Number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= Number; i++)
    {

        PictureBox temp = new PictureBox();
        panelName.Controls.Add(temp);
        temp.Width = 50;
        temp.Height = 350;
        temp.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        temp.BackColor = Color.Red;
        temp.Top = temp.Height * panelName.Controls.Count;
        temp.Left = 300;
        topPipe[i] = temp;
        topPipe[i].Visible = true;

    }
}
```